# Passing an environment to debugged program in Olly/Immunity

Tags: ollydbg, immunity-debugger

I am debugging a program that reads an environment variable. So far, I could not find how to launch it in Immunity/Olly with a custom environment.

Anybody know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child Inherits Parents Environment

```
   cmd /k set myenvironment=someenvironment & <path>ollydbg.exe  <path> debuggee.exe
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. Too bad olly cannot pass a custom env to the debuggee

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to blabb's answer, if you'd like to set the environment variable via a GUI, you can use http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32131/Dynamically-Add-Edit-Environment-Variables-of-Remo